# Headless wp with react. How to handle routes?

Tags: javascript

Wordpress by default already handles the routes to the requested pages but beeing a starter in react and wanting to learn more about it i've found out that you need to create all of your routes. This will extend the app development alot.. What's currently beeing used to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `react-router-dom` with `npm` or `yarn`.  Once you add those, you will need to import some modules into your React app.  You will need `BrowserRouter`, `Route`, `NavLink`, & `withRouter`.

`BrowserRouter` is to be on the outmost parent Component that manages the history API.  Ideally, you would just put your `<App />` component inside it in your `index.js` file, but I think it's simpler to not include 3 separate files in my comment and just wrapped my `<App />` response in it here instead.

Any component inside `BrowserRouter` can use `<Route />` and `<NavLink />`.  `Route` will trigger based on the request URL and you change the request URL either by manually typing an address or using a `<NavLink />` component.  At the bottom of the Dropdown component you will see I export the component inside `withRouter`.  This adds useful information to the component's props such as the current url slug.

Here is a simple example.

`yarn add react-router-dom`

```
// App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.scss';
import {wpAPI} from '../../data/api';
import FrontPage from '../../templates/FrontPage';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Post from '../Post/Post';
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';

// Create a React Component
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        pages: [],
        posts: [],
        postTypes: [],
        acf: [],
        events: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        var keys = Object.keys(this.state);

        for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            this.getPosts(keys[i]);
        }
    }

    renderContent() {
        if ( this.state.pages ) {
            const {pages} = this.state;

            return (
                // Outermost element, contains single root child element.
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <section id="app" className="animated fadeIn">
                        <Header />
                        <main>
                            // Path = Url after domain & protocal
                            // Use render prop to pass props to component, else use component prop ex. component={FrontPage}
                            <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <FrontPage {...props} pages={ pages } /> } />
                            <Route path="/about" exact render={(props) => <Post {...props} post={ this.state.pages[3] } /> } />
                        </main>
                        <Sidebar />
                        <Footer />
                    </section>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
        }

        return <Spinner message='loading...' />;
    }

    render() {
        return this.renderContent();
    }

    /**
     * Takes a post type, builds post type as array of post json in state
     *
     * @param  {[string]} type [Post Type]
     */
    getPosts = async (type) => {
        const response = await axios.get(wpAPI[type]);

        this.setState({[type]: response.data})
    }
};

export default App;
```

.

```
// Menu.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faChevronDown, faChevronUp } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Dropdown.scss';

library.add(faChevronDown, faChevronUp);

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        const {title, list, to} = props;

        this.state = {
            listOpen: false,
            title: title,
            list: list,
            to: to,
        };
        // console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleClickOutside(){
        this.setState({
            listOpen: false
        })
    }
    toggleList(){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            listOpen: !prevState.listOpen
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const {listOpen, title, list, to} = this.state;

        if ( list ) {
            return(
                <div className="dropdown dropdown__wrapper">
                    <header className="dropdown__header" onClick={() => this.toggleList()}>
                        <div className="dropdown__title">{title}</div>
                        {listOpen
                          ? <i className="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
                          : <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                        }
                    </header>
                    {listOpen && <ul className="dropdown__list">
                        {list.map((item) => (
                            <NavLink className="dropdown__item" key={item.id} to={item.to}>{item.title}</NavLink>
                        ))}
                    </ul>}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return(
            <div className="dropdown dropdown__wrapper">
                <div className="dropdown__header" onClick={() => this.toggleList()}>
                    <NavLink className="dropdown__title" to={to}>{title}</NavLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Dropdown);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to do it yourself. The REST API is only responsible for returning the data, the front end is *entirely* down to you.

I couldn't find any code that you could just drop into a project to handle routing, but [this article](https://lamosty.com/2015/11/10/react-wp-theme-smart-vs-dumb-components-react-router/) seemed to offer the most detail on doing it with React.